# Python Speed up csv manipulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, csv

Is there anyway to speed up the processing of this csv file manipulation? With a csv with 5000 entries it works fine but when there are 1,000,000+ entries it takes a long time.

```
r1 = csv.reader(open('file1.csv'))
r2 = csv.reader(open('file2.csv'))
with open(file3, 'w', newline='') as wf:
    writer = csv.writer(wf)
    entries = []
    first = True

    for child, a, b, c, parent, d in r1:
        if not child and not parent:
            continue
        if first:
            first = False
            continue
        entries.append([parent, child])

    first = True

    for child, _, _, _, parent, _ in r2:
        if not child and not parent:
            continue
        if first:
            first = False
            continue

        entries.append([parent, child])

    for p, c in entries:
        for sp, sc in entries:
            if p == sc:
                break
        else:
            entries.append([p, p])


    writer.writerow(["parent_new", "child_new"])
    writer.writerows(entries)
```

Also there is a line break between the header and the first row of data, anyway to remove this blank line when writing to the new csv?

Comment: Please be specific about what “long time” means. The blank line thing seems like it should be a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop:

```
    for p, c in entries:
        for sp, sc in entries:
            if p == sc:
                break
        else:
            entries.append([p, p])
```

will be taking quadratic time.

All that it seems to be doing is writing the values of `p` which do not equal any of the `child` values. As these values derive from the CSV file so must be strings, and are therefore hashable, you could save them (or more specifically, the unique values) in a set:

```
children = set(child for parent, child in entries)
```

It costs some more memory, but then you can do

```
    for p, c in entries:
        if p not in children:
            entries.append([p, p])
```

so this should then be linear time rather than quadratic (because set inclusion testing is essentially constant time).

---

On a more minor point, to remove the first row of each of the input files, instead of using your `first` variable (which you then have to test for on every iteration), simply call `next(r1)` before entering the loop (and discard the value) -- and similarly for `r2`.  That said, do not expect huge gain from doing this, because this is in the linear-time part of the code.  It is the O(n^2) bit mentioned above that is really important.